# Select users who is not member of group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the users who isn't a member of a group so I can fill a dropDownList for invitations.

I'm using T-SQL to do this.

Anyway lets say I have this table:

```
Username    Group_Id

David       1
Mathias     1
William     1
David       2
```

I want to select the members who isn't in group number 2 i.e. I only want Mathias and William, how do I do this? I've been trying for a while now, and I'm having trouble finding relevant info on google...

Comment: I think you mean david mathias and william (there are 3 in group 1)

Comment: David is a member of both groups, it looks like OP wants only those not in a specific group.

Comment: ah i stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct Username from table  
except 
select Username from table where group_id = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this using aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having sum(case when group_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of times the user appears in group 2 (in this case) and chooses only those users that appear one time.

Answer (score 1):

```
select username 
from t
where groupid not in (2)
```